# I got an email saying I used all my free dynos, but I have no idea which apps are using the hours?

Tags: heroku

How can I find out which app is using all the hours so I can upgrade it (I have ~30 apps)? Even if I click an app, I don't see anywhere that shows the hours used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Heroku dashbard, click on your profile icon in the top right corner, then click on "Account settings", and then select the Billing tab. Alternatively, just browse to https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/billing.

There you can see your "Free Dyno Usage" breakdown.